# Animate marker when click on a list item - google-maps-react

Tags: reactjs, maps, google-maps-react

I have built a project with [google-maps-react](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react).

I have this component structure

```
<App />
--- <FilterLocations />
------ <LocationsList />
--- <GoogleMaps />
------ <Marker />
```

I click on an item in the `<LocationList />` and I want it to make the corresponding marker in the `<GoogleMaps />` component bounce (represented by the `<Marker />` component which is provided by the package).

So in the `<GoogleMaps />` component I have this snippet:

```
{locations.map(location =>
   <Marker
      key={location.key}
      title={location.title}
      name={location.name}
      position={location.position}
      onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
      animation={(currentMarker === location.title)
         && this.props.google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE}
   />
)}
```

The `currentMarker` lives in the `<App />` state which is updated when we click on an item in the `<LocationsList />`, it is a string which is equal to the `location.title`.

So, when I use ReactDevTools, I see that the animation props is correctly set to 1 when the comparison is truthy, but it still doesn't bounce.

Any Idea?

Here is the whole project on [GitHub](https://github.com/maevanapcontact/fend-neighborhood-maps).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you decided to delete the project, in case you're still curious about the answer or anyone else might need it – in my project this is what worked:

I set my project up with the functions provided in the documentary [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react#infowindow). So while using the provided activeMarker I managed to get my marker bounce on click with adding this line inside my  component:

```
 {filterLocations.map((item) => {
    return (    
    <Marker
      animation={activeMarker ? (item.name === activeMarker.title ? '1' : '0') : '0'} 
    />
 )
})}
```

Yep, that's all to it, no additional functions needed. (Well assuming that you already got your markers respond to .click() on a list item.)